# Cortex-M3 Linking _sidata located incorrectly

Tags: linker, arm, stm32, cortex-m

I'm in the process of changing compiler from the Codesourcery Codebench Lite for ARM EABI gcc (v4.7.2) to the arm GCC 2014 q1 (v4.8.3) and am having an issue with the location of certain memory addresses defined in the linker file for my program. The chip is the STM32F103RBT6.

The Reset handler function is the first function called and is attempting to copy the data segment initialisers from flash to SRAM. The following code is executed:

```
void Reset_Handler(void)
{
    unsigned long *pulSrc, *pulDest;

    //
    // Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM.
    //
     pulSrc = &_sidata;
     for(pulDest = &_sdata; pulDest < &_edata; )
     {
         *(pulDest++) = *(pulSrc++);
     }

     //
     // Zero fill the bss segment.
     //
     for(pulDest = &_sbss; pulDest < &_ebss; )
     {
         *(pulDest++) = 0;
     }

     __libc_init_array();

     //
     // Call the application's entry point.
     //
     main();
}
```

Memory definitions are as follows:

```
MEMORY
{
      RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K  /* also change _estack below */
      FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
```

The _sidata value on the original (working) version of the program is defined as 0x8008400 but this value changes when I compile using the new compiler with the same linker script. The device is hard faulting because of this issue. I can hard code the values into the reset handler and the code executes fine so it's just an issue with these sections as far as I can tell. How can I ensure that these addresses are correct and why are they changing even though the linker script hasn't been changed?

stm32.ld:

```
/*
Linker script for STM32F10x
Copyright RAISONANCE 2007 (modified by Lanchon 1-Feb-2008)
You can use, copy and distribute this file freely, but without any waranty.
Configure memory sizes, end of stack and boot mode for your project here.
*/


/* include the common STM32F10x sub-script */
INCLUDE "STM32_COMMON.ld"

/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
  RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K  /* also change _estack below */
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

/* highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20005000;

/* include the section management sub-script */
/* (either "STM32_SEC_FLASH.ld" or "STM32_SEC_RAM.ld") */
INCLUDE "STM32_SEC_FLASH.ld"
```

STM32_COMMON.ld:

```
/*
Common part of the linker scripts for STR32 devices
Copyright RAISONANCE 2007
You can use, modify and distribute thisfile freely, but without any waranty.
*/


/* default stack sizes. 

These are used by the startup in order to allocate stacks for the different modes.
*/

__Stack_Size = 2048 ;

PROVIDE ( _Stack_Size = __Stack_Size ) ;

__Stack_Init = _estack  - __Stack_Size ;

/*"PROVIDE" allows to easily override these values from an object file or the commmand line.*/
PROVIDE ( _Stack_Init = __Stack_Init ) ;

/*
There will be a link error if there is not this amount of RAM free at the end.
*/
_Minimum_Stack_Size = 0x800 ;



/*
this sends all unreferenced IRQHandlers to reset
*/


PROVIDE (   Undefined_Handler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   SWI_Handler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   IRQ_Handler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   Prefetch_Handler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   Abort_Handler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   FIQ_Handler = 0 ) ;

PROVIDE (   NMIException = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   HardFaultException = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   MemManageException = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   BusFaultException = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   UsageFaultException = 0 ) ;
/* PROVIDE (   SVCHandler = 0 ) ; */
PROVIDE (   DebugMonitor = 0 ) ;
/* PROVIDE (   PendSVC = 0 ) ; */
/* PROVIDE (   SysTickHandler = 0 ) ; */
PROVIDE (   WWDG_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   PVD_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TAMPER_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   RTC_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   FLASH_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   RCC_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI0_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI1_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI2_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI3_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI4_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel1_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel2_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel3_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel4_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel5_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel6_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   DMAChannel7_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   ADC_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   USB_HP_CAN_TX_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   USB_LP_CAN_RX0_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   CAN_RX1_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   CAN_SCE_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI9_5_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM1_BRK_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM1_UP_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM1_TRG_COM_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM1_CC_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM2_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM3_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   TIM4_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   I2C1_EV_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   I2C1_ER_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   I2C2_EV_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   I2C2_ER_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   SPI1_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   SPI2_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   USART1_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   USART2_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   USART3_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   EXTI15_10_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   RTCAlarm_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;
PROVIDE (   USBWakeUp_IRQHandler = 0 ) ;



/******************************************************************************/
/*                       Peripheral memory map                                */
/******************************************************************************/
/*this allows to compile the ST lib in "non-debug" mode*/


/* Peripheral and SRAM base address in the alias region */
PERIPH_BB_BASE        = 0x42000000;
SRAM_BB_BASE          = 0x22000000;

/* Peripheral and SRAM base address in the bit-band region */
SRAM_BASE             = 0x20000000;
PERIPH_BASE           = 0x40000000;

/* Flash registers base address */
PROVIDE ( FLASH_BASE            = 0x40022000);
/* Flash Option Bytes base address */
PROVIDE ( OB_BASE               = 0x1FFFF800);

/* Peripheral memory map */
APB1PERIPH_BASE      = PERIPH_BASE  ;
APB2PERIPH_BASE      = (PERIPH_BASE + 0x10000) ;
AHBPERIPH_BASE       = (PERIPH_BASE + 0x20000) ;

PROVIDE ( TIM2            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000) ) ;
PROVIDE ( TIM3            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( TIM4            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( RTC             = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x2800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( WWDG            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x2C00) ) ;
PROVIDE ( IWDG            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x3000) ) ;
PROVIDE ( SPI2            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x3800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( USART2          = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x4400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( USART3          = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x4800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( I2C1            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x5400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( I2C2            = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x5800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( CAN             = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x6400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( BKP             = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x6C00) ) ;
PROVIDE ( PWR             = (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x7000) ) ;

PROVIDE ( AFIO            = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000) ) ;
PROVIDE ( EXTI            = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( GPIOA           = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( GPIOB           = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00) ) ;
PROVIDE ( GPIOC           = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x1000) ) ;
PROVIDE ( GPIOD           = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x1400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( GPIOE           = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x1800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( ADC1            = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x2400) ) ;
PROVIDE ( ADC2            = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x2800) ) ;
PROVIDE ( TIM1            = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x2C00) ) ;
PROVIDE ( SPI1            = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x3000) ) ;
PROVIDE ( USART1          = (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x3800) ) ;

PROVIDE ( DMA             = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x0000) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel1    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x0008) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel2    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x001C) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel3    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x0030) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel4    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x0044) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel5    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x0058) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel6    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x006C) ) ;
PROVIDE ( DMA_Channel7    = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x0080) ) ;
PROVIDE ( RCC             = (AHBPERIPH_BASE + 0x1000) ) ;

/* System Control Space memory map */
SCS_BASE              = 0xE000E000;

PROVIDE ( SysTick         = (SCS_BASE + 0x0010) ) ;
PROVIDE ( NVIC            = (SCS_BASE + 0x0100) ) ;
PROVIDE ( SCB             = (SCS_BASE + 0x0D00) ) ;
```

STM32_SEC_FLASH.ld:

```
/*
Common part of the linker scripts for STR71x devices in FLASH mode
(that is, the FLASH is seen at 0)
Copyright RAISONANCE 2005
You can use, modify and distribute thisfile freely, but without any waranty.
*/


EXTERN(Reset_Handler)
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Sections Definitions */

SECTIONS
{
    /* for Cortex devices, the beginning of the startup code is stored in the .isr_vector section, which goes to FLASH */
    .isr_vector :
    {
    . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))            /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH

    /* the program code is stored in the .text section, which goes to Flash */
    .text :
    {
    *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)

        *(.eh_frame_hdr)
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.gcc_except_table)
        *(.eh_frame_hdr)
        *(.eh_frame)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.init))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(0x4);
        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;

        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

        _etext = .;

        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .data secion */
        _sidata = _etext;
    } >FLASH

    /* .ARM.exidx is sorted, so has to go in its own output section.  */
    __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > FLASH
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __exidx_end = .;

    .data :
    {
        _flash_data = LOADADDR(.data);
        _data = .;
        _sdata = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
        _edata = .;
    } >RAM AT >FLASH

    /* This is the uninitialized data section */
    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
        _sbss = .;
        __bss_start__ = _sbss;

        *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
        _ebss = . ;
        __bss_end__ = _ebss;
    } >RAM

    PROVIDE ( end = _ebss );
    PROVIDE ( _end = _ebss );

    /* end of allocated ram _end */

    /* This is the user stack section 
    This is just to check that there is enough RAM left for the User mode stack
    It should generate an error if it's full.
     */
    ._usrstack :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _susrstack = . ;

        . = . + _Minimum_Stack_Size ;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _eusrstack = . ;
    } >RAM

}
```

Comment: and the rest of the linker script is...?

Comment: Put edits in for the full set of linker files

Comment: To what is `sidata` changed when it hardfaults? Could you try `_flash_data` instead of `sidata`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  For some reason, the linker doesn't set _sidata = _etext per what's in the linker script. Instead, the linker sets _sidata = _etext-2.   This resulted in the _sidata value being on a half word boundary, which causes the CPU to end up in the Default_Handler().

In your linker script you show the following:

```
_etext = .;
/* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .data secion */
_sidata = _etext;
```

To fix the problem, change it to the following so that _sidata is explicitly set to ".":

```
_etext = .;
/* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .data secion */
_sidata = .;
```

Comment: How do you know the `.data` section starts after `.text`? Is it a GCC convention to put the `.data` section after `.text`? From what I can see from the above linker script, there is `.ARM.exidx` right after `.text` ends.